# EE 5 - Code snippet in template appearing and disappearing on website

Tags: embeds, ee5

I have an code snippet embedded in one of my pages, that will disappear, and then, if I go into EE, open the template, see that *yes* it is there, and close the template, then it’s there again on the website.  So weird.

Page: https://brookechao.com/about

It’s a website content reader.  When it shows up, it’s an orange button right next to the heading text of the page.

The code is this:

```
<script async src="https://widget.websitevoice.com/wBI4odpYGBtGcKfXUCgasg"></script>
<script>
  window.wvData=window.wvData||{};function wvtag(a,b){wvData[a]=b;}
  wvtag('id', 'wBI4odpYGBtGcKfXUCgasg');
  wvtag('gender', 'female');
  wvtag('text-selector', 'article, .post-content, .blog-body, .post_content, .content, .section,.wsv-audio');
  wvtag('widget-style', {
    className: 'wv-circle-small',
    backgroundColor: '#F5953E',
    tooltipText: 'Audio Version of Content'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not clear what this has to do with EE - looks like a question about your javascript.  Perhaps you could clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  That include was a copy of another include, and so permissions were reset to none.  Meaning no one could see it, but if I logged in to check the templates involved, suddenly it would reappear (because I was logged in as a SuperAdmin).

Setting the permissions seems to have fixed the issue.